# I can't make allaning:roles package to work

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, roles, meteor-accounts

So, I have an initialisation file that runs on startup that calls the following server side Meteor function:

```
createAdminUser : function () {
    var userObject = {
        email: "admin@test.com",
        password: "abc123",
        profile: { first_name: "admin", last_name: "user"}
    };

    Accounts.createUser(userObject, function(){

    });

    Roles.addUsersToRoles(userObject, 'admin');
}
```

The user gets created successfully, but when I enter the javascript console to check whether the current user has 'admin' roles enabled, I get false returned:

```
input -> Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin')
output -> false
```

The documentation https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles#user-content-changes said that the Role function should only be called after the user has been created, which is (I'm pretty sure) what I'm doing, no?

If someone could shed light on my stupidity, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, 'Role') needs to be the id of the User object in the db (and returned by Accounts.createUser).

Try this:

```
var userObject = {
    email: "admin@test.com",
    password: "abc123",
    profile: { first_name: "admin", last_name: "user"}
};

var userId = Accounts.createUser(userObject);

Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, 'admin');
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the result is the same unfortunately. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what does `console.log(Meteor.user())` say?